# how to login with spring boot and angular 2

Tags: spring, rest, angular

I have a Front end application that runs on http:// localhost:5555, with angular 2

On the other hand, I have a Back end application running with spring boot on http:// localhost:8080/, that provide a REST Api for my angular 2 application.

Sending requests from http://localhost:5555/ to http://localhost:8080/ works as well.

what is the best way to authenticate users ,I read so many articles, but I couldn't find a solution.

Comment: post the code, code

Answer (score 0):

you need to creating cross-origin with `@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:5555")` in controller file